# Keep getting "Does not have minimum availability" in Kubernetes cluster when deploying workload

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently running a Kubernetes cluster on a n1 standard1 node (1vCPU and 3.75GB memory).I tried to deploy 4 workloads.

I have set resource request and limit as 100m and 128Mi (for container) for each deployment, but when I tried to deploy my 3rd pod, I keep getting not having enough CPU availability even the node is using only 9% CPU at the same time.

Does anyone know what might be going on? Any response would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share your `Deployment` yaml and provide more details about your **kubernetes cluster** ? How did you set it up ? As far as I understand this is not **GKE** but something you set up on your own on **GCE VM** e.g. with **kubeadm**, am I right ?

Comment: The main reason why you could get "not enough cpu" is not because of the limit but because of the **requests**. Please run the `$ kubectl describe node` and check how much of allocated (requested) CPU is assigned to a node.

Comment: I reproduced your setup and found some potential things that should be addressed when it comes to cluster resources (usage, requests, limits). Also, there is dedicated `GKE` documentation related to troubleshooting: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#does_not_have_minimum_availability .

Comment: Hello @BinVes, any progress with this issue ? Dawid's answer assumes you're using **GKE** however you didn't mention it explicitly in your question, could you confirm that `google-kubernetes-engine` tag wasn't added by mistake ?

Answer (score 2):

The most probable cause that the following error is showing:

- "Does not have minimum availability”

[image: GKE WORKLOAD]

Is that there are some objects (like `Pods`) not allocated inside of the cluster.

There are some links referencing the same message:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Troubleshooting: Does not have minimum availability](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#does_not_have_minimum_availability)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: GCP Kubernetes workload does not have minimum availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452120/gcp-kubernetes-workload-does-not-have-minimum-availability)*

---

Focusing specifically on the example showed in the question.

The setup is following:

- 1 `GKE` node with: `1 vCPU` and `3.75` GB of `RAM`

The resources scheduled onto this single node cluster:

- 4 `Deployments` where **each** have following fields:

```yaml
        resources:
          requests: # <-- IMPORTANT
            cpu: "100m" # <-- IMPORTANT
            memory: "128Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "128Mi"
```

For an example I tried to replicate setup as close as possible to the one in the question:

- `$ kubectl get pods`

```sh
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-four-99d88fccb-v664b     0/1     Pending   0          51m
nginx-one-8584c66446-rcw4p     1/1     Running   0          53m
nginx-three-5bcb988986-jp22f   1/1     Running   0          51m
nginx-two-6c9545d7d4-mrpw6     1/1     Running   0          52m
```

As you can see there is a `Pod` that is in `Pending` state. Further investigation implies:

- `$ kubectl describe pod/nginx-four-99d88fccb-v664b`

A lot of information will show about the `Pod` but the part that needs to be checked is `Events`:

```sh
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  56m (x2 over 56m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.
  Normal   Scheduled         56m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-two-6c9545d7d4-mrpw6 to gke-gke-old-default-pool-641f10b7-36qb
  Normal   Pulling           56m                kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal   Pulled            56m                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx"
  Normal   Created           56m                kubelet            Created container nginx
  Normal   Started           56m                kubelet            Started container nginx
```

As you can see from above output:

- `FailedScheduling: ... 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu`

As posted in the question:

> I keep getting not having enough cpu availability even the node is using only 9% cpu at the same time.

This CPU availability is strictly connected to the **Allocated resources**. You can have CPU usage in the midst of 10% and still run into `Insufficient CPU` messages. Here is why:

> When you create a Pod, the Kubernetes scheduler selects a node for the Pod to run on. Each node has a maximum capacity for each of the resource types: the amount of CPU and memory it can provide for Pods. **The scheduler ensures that, for each resource type, the sum of the resource requests of the scheduled Containers is less than the capacity of the node. Note that although actual memory or CPU resource usage on nodes is very low, the scheduler still refuses to place a Pod on a node if the capacity check fails.** This protects against a resource shortage on a node when resource usage later increases, for example, during a daily peak in request rate.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Configuration: Manage resources containers: How pods with resource requests are scheduled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled)*

Take a look on the `resources.requests` section in the part of `Deployment` I included earlier. It is specified there that each `Pod` in the `Deployment` want a guarantee that `100m` of `CPU` time will be available in the cluster. 4x`100m` = `400m`.

If you run (after applying the workload):

- `$ kubectl describe node`

```yaml
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                      Requests          Limits
  --------                      --------          ------
  cpu                          -->939m (99%)<--     501m (53%)
  memory                        1081Mi (40%)      1721Mi (65%)
  ephemeral-storage             0 (0%)            0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi                 0 (0%)            0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-gce-pd     0                 0
```

There is already allocated the `939M`  CPU from a `1000M` (`3/4` `Pods` are scheduled). That's why one of the `Pod` cannot be scheduled (even when the `CPU` usage is 10%).

> A side note!
>
> This would be specific to each and every cluster but this one reported `639m` of `CPU` requested before any workload was scheduled.

To fix that you can either:

- Change the `.resources.requests` section
- Use [VPA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler) to recommend the `requests` and `limits`
- Use different node type
- Enable autoscaling

---

Additional resources:

- [Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Configuration: Manage resources containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler)*

Comment: @BinVes Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `kubectl describe node XXX` to describe the node where you can't allocate more resources. Likely you would need to increase the node resources deploying a new nodepool  or spread the workload in more nodes enabling autoscaling.